# open form on a specific tab vba access 2003

Tags: vba, ms-access-2003

I'd like to open a form on a specific tab.
The form is not the current one.

```
Function OpenOnTab(tabIndex As Integer)
    Dim frmName As String
    Dim frm As Form
    frmName = "MyFormName"

    'open form
    DoCmd.OpenForm frmName

    'go to tab
    frm = Forms!frmName 'error "incorrect property use"

    'todo set form on tabIndex
    'maybe using frm.TabCtl0.Value = tabIndex but I con't try 

End Function
```

I'd like in a first time to set the form in my variable and set the form on the tabIndex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find the solution :)

```
frm.SelTop = myTabIndex
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what that error is. Probably because you are not using the `Set` keyword (see below)

I would go with the following :

```
Function OpenOnTab(myTabIndex As Integer)
    Dim frmName As String, frm As Form, t As Integer, ctrl As Control
    frmName = "Form1"

    'open form
    DoCmd.OpenForm frmName

    'go to tab
    Set frm = Forms(frmName)
    For Each ctrl In frm
        With ctrl
            t = -1
            On Error GoTo errHandler
            t = ctrl.TabIndex
            If t = 1 Then
                MsgBox ctrl.Name
                Forms(frmName).Form.Controls(ctrl.Name).SetFocus
                Exit Function
            End If
            On Error GoTo 0
        End With
    Next

errHandler:
    If Err.Number = 438 Then ''property not supported for labels, etc
        Resume Next
    Else
        MsgBox Err.Number & vbCrLf & Err.Description
    End If

End Function
```

**-- Edit (different requirements) --**

Navigating to a row is different. Simply use the move operation.

The case for `index > 1` is added because in some versions of Access, `.Move 0` causes an error.

```
Function OpenOnTab(myIndex As Integer)
    Dim frmName As String
    frmName = "Form1"

    'open form
    DoCmd.OpenForm frmName

    If myIndex > 1 Then Forms(frmName).Form.Recordset.Move myIndex - 1

exit function
```

Comment: In this case the code set the focus on one of my control. I have a form, on the bottom of the form I can navigate between my table rows. When I open my form the current row is always the first one. I'd like do change this row number using vba

Comment: I find the solution `frm.SelTop = myTabIndex`